# Real time plotting of BLE data using Bleak and PyQtGraph packages

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-asyncio, pyqtgraph

I am trying to plot sensor data in real time using an ESP32-based sensor and BLE. I've attempted to use Bleak and combine the simple [scrolling example](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/scrollingPlots.py) from the PyQtGraph package. I know that the sensor data is been read correctly from the ESP32, but there is no plot appearing, so clearly integrating the code incorrectly.

My current code:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient
import time
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

# BLE peripheral ID
address = "6C9F597F-7085-4AAB-806B-D2558588D50D"
UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

# Plot details
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Scrolling Plots')
p1 = win.addPlot()
data1 = np.zeros(5)
curve1 = p1.plot(data1)


async def run(address, loop):
    global data1

    while True:
        time.sleep(5)

        async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
            data = await client.read_gatt_char(UUID)

            #Parse sensor data from BLE characteristic
            sensor_data = data.decode('utf_8')
            print(sensor_data)
            sensor_data = sensor_data.split(",")
            temperature = sensor_data[4]

            #Update the array with newest data so plot will appear scroll
            def update():
                print(temperature)
                data1[:-1] = data1[1:]
                data1[-1] = temperature
                curve1.setData(data1)

        timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(update)
        timer.start(1000)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run(address, loop))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: I would expect the ESP32 to do notifications of the temperature. Typically you would do the plotting in the notify callback and not use the `sleep`. Reference in the Bleak documentation:
https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=start_notify#bleak.backends.client.BaseBleakClient.start_notify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use time.sleep in pyqtgraph.

pyqtgraph does not support asyncio by default but you can use the [`asyncqt`](https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt) module(`python -m pip install asyncqt`) or [`qasync`](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync) module (`python -m pip install qasync`) that creates a new eventloop that does support Qt.

```py
import asyncio

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

from bleak import BleakClient

from asyncqt import QEventLoop, asyncSlot

# BLE peripheral ID
address = "6C9F597F-7085-4AAB-806B-D2558588D50D"
UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"


class Window(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self, loop=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._loop = loop

        self.setWindowTitle("pyqtgraph example: Scrolling Plots")
        plot = self.addPlot()
        self._data = np.zeros(5)
        self._curve = plot.plot(self.data)
        self._client = BleakClient(address, loop=self._loop)

    @property
    def client(self):
        return self._client

    async def start(self):
        await self.client.connect()
        self.start_read()

    async def stop(self):
        await self.client.disconnect()

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @property
    def curve(self):
        return self._curve

    async def read(self):
        data = await self.client.read_gatt_char(UUID)
        sensor_data = data.split(",")
        if len(sensor_data) >= 5:
            temperature_str = sensor_data[4]
            try:
                temperature = float(temperature_str)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f"{temperature_str} not is float")
            else:
                self.update_plot(temperature)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.start_read)

    def start_read(self):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.read(), loop=self._loop)

    def update_plot(self, temperature):
        self.data[:-1] = self.data[1:]
        self.data[-1] = temperature
        self.curve.setData(self.data)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super().closeEvent(event)
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.client.stop(), loop=self._loop)


def main(args):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(args)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    with loop:
        asyncio.ensure_future(window.start(), loop=loop)
        loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't work because I get the error ```'BleakClientCoreBluetooth' object has no attribute 'start'```. I tried to replace it with ```start_notify()```  but  just gives more errors.

Comment: Thanks but am now getting ```bleak.exc.BleakError: Characteristic beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8 was not found!```. It should find that characterisitic because when I run the [example](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=client.read_gatt_char()#usage) in the Bleak docs, it works fine.