# Troubleshooting Connection Issues between Bleak and Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an embedded device that transmits acceleration data via Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). The device supports the Nordic UART Service (NUS), which enables the exchange of mass data via BLE. To capture and visualize the data on my PC, I decided to use the Python library bleak. For the first test, I tried the [uart_service.py](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/uart_service.py) file from the bleak examples, which worked flawlessly.

The Python library Matplotlib is not known for its plotting speed, but I came across an interesting post on optimizing rendering with blitting, and achieved a frame rate of over 200 frames per second (fps). [link1,](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/blitting.html) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126176/fast-live-plotting-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

While trying to integrate Matplotlib's fast example and Bleak's uart_service.py, I ran into a problem. Although Bleak successfully connected to the embedded device, I saw it in the terminal output on the PC, which is connected to the embedded device via UART, but the code didn't go any further, it was blocked. When I commented out the matplotlib code, the application ran without any problems.
I debugged the code with the matplotlib inside and the code stops at the point where the bleak client wants to connect to the device, line (62),`async with BleakClient(device) as client:` .**What am I missing here?**

I have also looked the following questions ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172127/real-time-plotting-of-ble-data-using-bleak-and-pyqtgraph-packages),  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268254/bleak-integration-in-pyqt5) ) which tried to combine pyqtgraph with bleak ,but it is not that easy as the pyqtgraph does not support asyncio and then you need to use a different module.The Qt code interface has been changed and the code in the questions can no longer be compiled. I also wrote a code pyqtgraph and bleak, but it does not work.

Thanks for the help.

The Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner

address = 'E6:B0:76:20:OE:41'
UART_TX_CHAR_UUID = "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
NAME = "NUS"


def init_matplot():
    global ax, fig, ln0, ln1, ln2, bg
    y = np.zeros(200)
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    (ln0,) = ax.plot(x, y, animated=True)
    (ln1,) = ax.plot(x, y, animated=True)
    (ln2,) = ax.plot(x, y, animated=True)

    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.ion()
    bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)
    ax.draw_artist(ln0)
    ax.draw_artist(ln1)
    ax.draw_artist(ln2)


def callback(characteristic, data):
    trim_str = data.decode('utf-8').split(",")
    val_x = float(trim_str[0])
    val_y = float(trim_str[1])
    val_z = float(trim_str[2])
    print(f"{val_x, val_y, val_z}")
    global ax, fig, ln0, ln1, ln2, bg
    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg)
    ln0.set_ydata(val_x)
    ln1.set_ydata(val_y)
    ln2.set_ydata(val_z)
    ax.draw_artist(ln0)
    ax.draw_artist(ln1)
    ax.draw_artist(ln2)
    # copy the image to the GUI state, but screen might not be changed yet
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    # flush any pending GUI events, re-painting the screen if needed
    fig.canvas.flush_events()


async def start_app():
    device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(address)
    if device is None:
        print("Address could not be found")
        device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_name(NAME)
        if device is None:
            print("Name could not be found")
            exit(-1)
        else:
            print("Device matched on name.")
    else:
        print("Device matched on address.")
    print("Connecting...")
    async with BleakClient(device) as client:
        print("Connected")
        await client.start_notify(UART_TX_CHAR_UUID, callback)
        await asyncio.sleep(380.0)
        await client.stop_notify(UART_TX_CHAR_UUID)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_matplot()
    asyncio.run(start_app())
```

Comment: Hey Joshua, it might be that you have the same problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76402493/why-does-fig-axs-plt-subplots3-1-sharex-true-prevent-connection-to-a-bleakclie